# Bound columns require a field or property access expression

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In kendo Grid I want to show string based on Character if its grater than 50 then need to show with sub string. But I am getting Error

Here Is the Message of Error

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Bound columns require a field or property access expression.
Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridBoundColumn..ctor(Grid grid, Expression> expression)**

And Here is the line where I am getting this error

```html
columns.Bound((c=>c.Group_Name.Length>50 ? c.Group_Name.Substring(0,50):c.Group_Name)).Title("Group Name");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ClientTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/templates/column-templates):

```
column.Template(t => { })
    .ClientTemplate("<span>#= Group_Name.length > 50 ? Group_Name.substring(0,50) : Group_Name) #</span>")
    .Title("Group Name");
```

Comment: Yes thank you , later i have used client template  and called javascript function which return me sub string if its greater than 50 characters .ClientTemplate("#: GetColumnNameSubstring(Group_Name) #")